# Value of a complex function inside an analytic region

Tags: complex-analysis

I encountered the following question which I am struggling with:

> Suppose $f$ is analytic on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| \le 2 \}$ and $f(z) = 3$ everywhere on the circle $|z|=2$. What is the value of $f$ at $z=1$?

All I can think of is about the Cauchy's integral formula which states that for a contour $\gamma$ and $f$ analytic in a simply connected domain containing $\gamma$:
$$f(1) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}{\frac{f(z)}{z-1}} dz$$

Then I can use as a contour the circle $|z|=2$ and
$$f(1) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=2}{\frac{3}{z-1}dz} = \frac{1}{2\pi i} [3ln(e^{i\theta}-1)]^{2\pi}_{0}$$

but this doesn't work. What is the correct/immediate way of deducing the statement above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The residue is $3$, so we should get $3$.

That is, you have applied Cauchy's integral formula.   Next apply the residue theorem.

So $\frac1{2\pi i}\cdot 6\pi i=3$.

Comment: But isn't Cauchy's residue theorem valid only for a region where there is a singularity? In my question the function is defined to be analytic inside the region $|z| <2$

Comment: Yes, but let $g(z)=\frac3{z-1}$.

Comment: Alright so $f(z)$ is analytic but $f(z)/z-1$ is not, correct?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I'm saying.  You can just replace $f(z)$ by $3$, in the residue theorem.